# How to Call Python from R in a Windows OS?

Tags: python, r, statistics

I'm looking for a way to call python within R on a Windows operating system. Since there appears to be no readily available R package for this (at least no package that's been updated recently), I'm looking for leads on how to write a set of commands in an R script that can then be sent in batch mode to python.

In short, how can I call python from R in a Windows OS?

Edit: To clarify, I am **not** asking about calling R from python; rather I am asking about calling python from R.

Update: Based on what I've gathered so far, here's a basic set of commands on running python from R in a Windows OS:

```
# (1) basic python commands called from R
system('python -c "a = 2 + 2; print a"') 
system('python -c "a = \'hello world\' ; print a; import pandas"')

# (2) if you have a python file you've already created (which I've referred to as "my.py"), then you can run it in R as follows:
system("python C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\my.py")

# or alternatively:
system('python -c "import sys; sys.path.append(\'C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\'); import my;"')
```

Neither of these approaches is at the level of interactivity needed for fluid data analysis using python in R on a Windows OS. The most straightforward solution might be to write a simple R function that (1) exports a specified R data frame to python, (2) parses python syntax written in R (using `stringr` and `system('python -c')`), and then (3) optionally exports the data back to R. It'd be a pseudo-interactivity in R based on updating a temporary python file through the R console.

Comment: Here is another useful link regarding calling python from R. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155703/call-python-with-system-in-r-to-run-a-python-script-emulating-the-python-conso

Comment: This is a great question since it alerts me that calling python from R is possible. However, can OP perhaps educate people like me why this is something one may want to do?

Comment: Do I need to install any special library to Python? Running that code above in RStudio with having Python opened did nothing :((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this package [PythonInR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PythonInR/index.html)

Comment: In case you have explore [rPython-win](https://github.com/cjgb/rPython-win), how does it compare to using PythonInR?

Comment: @AnalyticalMonk. When I try rPython-win, I am getting this error: installing to library 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.5'
ERROR:  Unix-only package
* removing 'C:/Users/.../Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rPython'
In R CMD INSTALL. Any ideas how to solve this error?

Comment: @A.Shlash. Likewise, when I try PythonlnR, I get the error: Warning message:
In pyConnectionCheck() : R isn't connected to Python! Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Make a python file....

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Mar  9 09:55:46 2016

@author: Subhash Jaini
"""

import pandas as pd
d = {'First' : [1., 2., 3.],'Second' : [1,2,3]}


AA = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(AA)
```

---

save it to a place (I used c:/deleteme/pythonRun.py)

In R, run this code.

```
#calls the python script to run in shell
BlobReturnedFromPython = shell('python c:/deleteme/pythonRun.py',intern=TRUE)
#get the first line and turn it to your header
HEADER = gsub(" ","",unlist(strsplit(as.character(BlobReturnedFromPython[1]),"  ")))[-1]
#all the rest of the data is non header data
NONHEADER = BlobReturnedFromPython[2:(length(BlobReturnedFromPython)-1)]
#turnthat blob (which is seperated by about 4 spaces )
DATA = data.frame(sapply(NONHEADER,function(x){unlist(strsplit(x,"    "))}))
#brings those names into the data set
names(DATA) <- HEADER
DATA
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that might actually work on a Windows OS:

http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-python/

The article describes a setup for Ubuntu, where Rcpp is used as an intermediate layer between R and Python. Although I have not tried that yet, I currently see no reason why this solution should not work on Windows as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for calling python from R then try [rPython](http://www.r-bloggers.com/calling-python-from-r-with-rpython/) but it isn't for windows OS.
Or try [RSPython](http://www.omegahat.org/RSPython/) has a weak support for windows. An other useful [link](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/r/rpy/).

At last you can try to use something like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to execute linux application on your windows OS. More work load will be to use some virtual environments like [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/) or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) on windows and install linux and carry out your work.

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but rPython does not work in a Windows OS. As the blog you link to concludes: "The main drawback to the rPython package is that it currently doesn’t run on Windows." Your other links are also to packages that don't work in Windows, as one of the authors writes about RSPython: "NOTE: this currently does not allow one to embedd R within Python on Windows."