# Adding a new language to knitr, with variable persistence

Tags: r, coffeescript, knitr

I'd like to extend `knitr` with a new language, or more than one.  Imitating the source code for the `eng_go` function, [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/engine.R#L556), yields code like this, which adds CoffeeScript CLI support, for example.

```
knitr::knit_engines$set( cs = function ( options ) {
  f = tempfile( 'code', '.', fileext = '.coffee' )
  writeLines( c(
    'console.log try',
    paste0( '  ', options$code ),
    'catch error then error.message'
  ), f )
  on.exit( unlink( f ), add = TRUE )
  cmd = Sys.which( 'coffee' )
  extra = if ( options$eval ) {
    args <- paste0( ' ', f )
    message( 'running: ', cmd, args )
    tryCatch(
      system2( cmd, args, stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE, env = options$engine.env ),
      error = function ( e ) {
        if ( !options$error ) stop( e )
        'Error in executing CoffeeScript code'
      }
    )
  }
  if ( options$results == 'hide' ) extra = NULL
  knitr::engine_output( options, options$code, extra )
} )
```

You can put that in a code chunk in an `.Rmd` file, and the very next code chunk can be of type `cs`, and will be interpreted as I intend.

*My question is this:  Is there any documentation on extending that basic functionality with new features?*

In particular, I'd like to know how to make variables persist across chunks (by processing all chunks at once??) and to customize output formatting based on the type of the resulting object.

Comment: you need to come up with a way to do environment serialization & deserialization or have a language REPL running in the background and feed the code to it.

Comment: Please let me know if you figure out a universal approach. I have been looking forward to a better solution than this since 2013: https://github.com/yihui/runr I have a few relevant SO questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10155703/559676 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/17820740/559676. BTW, there has been [simple support](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/engine.R) for `coffeescript` in knitr, e.g., https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blame/master/080-engine-coffeescript.Rmd

Comment: I see what you mean.  For each language you add, you end up writing a new module in R and a new module in that language.  Yes, that seems less than ideal.  Any reason you're not just running the existing REPLs for these languages and piping text input to them?  Then you get parsing and input segmentation for free.  Wouldn't that produce a generic solution, in which each language simply needs to provide the name of its REPL command, plus regexps for the two types of prompts to watch for?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if the best way to solve this problem is to make knitr speak the [Jupyter messaging protocol](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/development/messaging.html) and thus get access to [all these languages](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels) for free.  Also, I am not sure how to move this conversation over to "chat" but am glad to do so if you prefer, @YihuiXie.

Comment: Note that the Jupyter messaging protocol is what PythonTeX is planning to do, eventually: https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/115